# QVector no match for 'operator='

Tags: c++, qt, constructor, header, qvector

I've got a problem initializing a QVector in a class constructor. This is the line in my header-file:

```
QVector<Person *> p;
```

This is the line in my constructor:

```
this->p = new QVector<Person *>();
```

And this is the error:

```
Error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'QVector<Person*>' and 'QVector<Person*>*')
 this->p = new QVector<Person *>();
         ^
```

I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: Stop writing Java.  In C++, `new` is for dynamic memory allocation, not general-purpose object creation.  For that matter, object creation happens in the constructor's initializer list, not its body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for `new` here. Despite the fact that `p` is an object of type `QVector` and not a pointer to it, `p` is initialized automatically since `QVector` has a default-constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to dynamically (with `new`) allocate `QVector` because you declared it as statically allocated member.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a QVector * to a QVector; writing

QVector p;

is enough, your member variable p is already a QVector.
You can copy QVectors around without incurring too big of a performance hit because of the use of the PIMPL idiom. Copies are copy on write, which means that modifying the copy won't modify the original, the copy however will only occur at the point you write (or resize) the new one.